# How to sort numbers in text files?

Tags: command-line, sort

I made a file using `ed` and named it `numeric`. Its content is as follow:

```
-100
-10
0
99
11
-56
12
```

Then I executed this command on terminal:

```
sort numeric
```

And the result was:

```
0
-10
-100
11
12
-56
99
```

And of course this output was not at all expected!

Comment: What is your locale? `env | grep -E '^(LANG|LC)'`

Comment: Then what as expected?

Comment: @glenn my language has been set to english indian . But still it does not seem in alphabetical order!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To sort numerals you need to use `-g` parameter.

```
sort -g <file_name>
```

Example:

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ cat nums
-100
-10
0
99
11
-56
12
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ sort -g nums
-100
-56
-10
0
11
12
99
```

If only integers are used, `sort -n` is preferred. It should work faster.

Comment: Isn't `-n` (`--numeric-sort`) preferred for integer data? Even the info page says *"Use this option only if there is no alternative; it is much slower than `--numeric-sort` (`-n`) and it can lose information when converting to floating point."*

Comment: I was experimenting . But even if alphabetical sorting is default still the result is not clear!

Comment: @steeldriver In this case it does not matter. But how do we know OP wants to sort only integers?

Comment: @da6932 It is alphabetical, but leading `-` is ignored.